# xamarin.forms, integration with libvlcsharp

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, uwp, libvlcsharp

did someone know how to solve this?

I created Xamarin.forms project with UWP, Android and IOS

Everytime when I try to run project get this error

"LibVLCSharp.Shared.VLCException: 'Failed to load libvlc.dll, error 126. Please make sure that this library, libvlccore.dll and the plugins are copied to the `AppX` folder. For that, you can reference the `VideoLAN.LibVLC.WindowsRT` NuGet package.'"
Yes I added LibVLCSharp and ibVLCSharp.Forms

this is bitbucket repo (public)

```
https://alekswhite@bitbucket.org/alekswhite/video.git
```

Comment: Have you install `LibVLCSharp` and `LibVLCSharp.Forms` nuget package for the solution, and  have you call initial method in each client project(`LibVLCSharpFormsRender.init()`).

Answer (score 0):

To allow updates of the libvlc library, it is not installed by default.

Did you install the LibVLC package that corresponds to your platform(in each platform-specific project) ?

See the Readme of the repository for that.

If you did install the LibVLC package, please update your question with a repository with a sample code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: yes I added both nuget packages, https://alekswhite@bitbucket.org/alekswhite/video.git

Comment: Don't reference `VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows` in your shared project

Comment: Also, don't reference `VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows` in your iOS project...

Comment: Just start from one of the official samples in the main repo

Comment: You really need to install the NuGet package for your platform in your platform-specific project.